# How to send redis metrics to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have install redis on Amazon Linux2 what is the best way to send redis metrics to cloudwatch.
Collectd is installed but not able to install `collectd-redis`

```
sudo yum install collectd-redis
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd 283 packages excluded due to repository priority protections Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package collectd-redis.x86_64 0:5.8.1-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: collectd(x86-64) = 5.8.1-1.el7 for package: collectd-redis-5.8.1-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libhiredis.so.0.12()(64bit) for package: collectd-redis-5.8.1-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: collectd-redis-5.8.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: collectd(x86-64) = 5.8.1-1.el7
               Installed: collectd-5.8.1-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-collectd)
                   collectd(x86-64) = 5.8.1-1.amzn2.0.2
               Available: collectd-5.8.1-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2extra-collectd)
                   collectd(x86-64) = 5.8.1-1.amzn2.0.1 Error: Package: collectd-redis-5.8.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: libhiredis.so.0.12()(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```